# Upgrading a Second Generation Managed Package to next version

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, security-review, package.xml, second-generation-packaging

We have created a Second Generation Managed Package and published it in AppExchange and we need to release the next version with few changes in existing codes. These are the things which we don't understand?

1. Should we create the patch version?
2. While creating the new package version, do I need to add the entire classes and components in package xml or only the changed classes and components?
3. Does the newly created package version will once again go into the Salesforce AppExchange Security Review process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You create a patch if you need to fix bugs against a previously released version and you are not adding new functionality (or more specifically not adding any new "components" - which includes custom objects, custom fields, top-level apex classes, validation rules etc.). If you are simply evolving the package, adding new functionality, it's a new major/minor version release and not a patch.
2. The `package.xml` is irrelevant to managed packages. The package content is dictated by the content of the package's `packageDirectory` folder as defined in the `sfdx-project.json`.
3. You submit through the same process but it will be auto-approved (without cost), if you want to select this version on your app exchange listing.

An example of the `sfdx-project.json` is below, showing how `force-app` directory holds the content for the "My Package" 2GP, and that the `force-unpackaged` directory contains non-packaged metadata used on the scratch org for development purposes only:

```json
{
  "namespace": "something",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "58.0",
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true,
      "package": "My Package",
      "versionNumber": "1.5.0.NEXT",
      "versionDescription": "Some description",
      "ancestorId": "My Package@1.4.0",
      "definitionFile": "config/project-scratch-def.json",
      "postInstallScript": "something.Installer",
      "dependencies": [
        {
          "package": "..."
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "path": "force-unpackaged"
    }
  ],
  "packageAliases": {
    "My Package@1.4.0": "04x1z0000012345ABC",
    ...
  }
}
```

Being a 2GP package, all metadata for the package must always appear within the package's folder. This folder's content is the "source of truth" for the content of the package, and that folder's content should come directly from version control (so meaning that version control is your packaging "source of truth" - i.e. version control contains everything that IS the package).

It may not cover all your questions in detail, but it's worth reviewing the [ISV documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_create_pkg_ver_promote.htm) plus the [sfdx packaging docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev_2gp_developing_2gp_packages.htm).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Phil. Could you please explain this line a bit more "The package content is dictated by the content of the package's package Directory folder as defined in the sfdx-project.xml", Should the package Directory have all the components related to the package or only the components which are edited?

Comment: @S1th answer updated.

Comment: Thanks Phil. Now I have created the patch version with few apex code changes.

Comment: Hi @Phil W , I got stuck with another issue. We want to create an another Second Generation Managed Package which works only on Multi-Currency Enabled orgs and we want this package to be available for all Salesforce Editions, so while running the package creation command, we are getting various errors regarding the reference of CurrencyISOCode field in apex classes.

I have posted this question, this is the link.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/412262/unable-to-create-second-generation-managed-package-with-multi-currency-enabled

Could you please help me.