# Unable to Create Second Generation Managed Package with Multi-Currency Enabled

Tags: multi-currency, scratch-org-definition-file, second-generation-packaging, package-dependency

We want to create a Second Generation Managed Package which works only on Multi-Currency Enabled orgs and all the Supported Salesforce Editions, so while running the package creation command, we are getting various errors regarding the CurrencyISOCode field in apex classes. The error we are getting is:

"Can't create package version. This package may be attempting to reference features or org settings, and you either didn't specify a definition file, or it contains an error."

This my config/project-scratch-def.json definition file looks like:

```
{
"features": ["MultiCurrency"]
}
```

I haven't added the edition in definition file because we want this package to work in all editions.

After adding the definition file, while running the package creation command, I got the error like this:

INSERT FAILED: INVALID OR NULL RESTRICTED PICKLIST, Opportunity Currency: Invalid Currency Code: USD

As I have used USD CurrencyISOCode in my test classes.
Do I need to enable Multi-Currency Enabled in my Devhub Org and Add the USD currencyISOCode to it?

Comment: Sounds like you need to ensure your `config/project-scratch-def.json` includes the correct runes to enable multi-currency for your scratch orgs/implicit release org. Take a look [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Phil, I have added the config/project-scratch-def.json file, still I got few errors, I have updated my question. Please check it.

Comment: I know multicurrency specification in the config has changed over time, and I wonder if that documentation is actually correct, now I look at it. See [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000IOQlQAO). However, also note [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_enable_multicurrency_implications.htm&type=5) about codes you can use in unit tests.

Comment: Thanks Phil, by using the approach mentioned by you, we are able to create the package. We specified edition as Developer in config/project-scratch-def.json file, does this make the package only installed in developer editions or Does the package can be installed in any Salesforce Edition?

Comment: AFAIK, you should be able to use Developer or Partner Developer edition (if you are a Salesforce partner) without impact on the editions you can install on, assuming you only use appropriate features that can be enabled on the target edition.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Phil.